# Redo and Undo on a String, how to implement?

Tags: java, stack, undo, undo-redo

I want to implement a redo and undo function to my sudoku game. However it seems to not be working. Here is some of my code:

**Sudoku class:**

Declarations,(info gets assigned first grid value in constructor, so starting length is 1):

```
Board board;
String[][] redoS;
Stack<String[][]> info = new Stack<String[][]>();
```

Undo and redo functions:

```
public boolean undo(){
        if(info.size()>2){
            redoS=(String[][])info.pop();   
            board.grid=(String[][])info.pop();
               return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
public boolean redo(){
        if(redoS!=null){
            board.grid=(String[][])redoS;
            info.push(redoS);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

(Add input method has info.push() and remove has info.pop().)

**Game controller file/class:**

```
@FXML
    public void gjenta(){
        if(game.redo()){
            console.setText("Gjentok");
        }
        console1.setText(game.toString());
    }
@FXML
    public void angre(){
        if(game.undo()){
            console.setText("Angret");
        }
        console1.setText(game.toString());
    }
```

Getting 0 errors, the board is not changing when methods are called.

Comment: You'll need to give more details; since we can't run the program, so it's very hard for us to identify an unknown problem that could be anywhere.

Comment: @SteveSmith seems that the undo and redo functions are not working. This is my first time using a stack but cant figure out the reason why.. When i click on undo or redo nothing happens, console prints out text like it should but grid is not changing.